# How can I make the texture to appear once the game is played?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, game-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

I had to add letter on the cube so i did it using UV mapping

[image]

 but once I play the game only materials are displayed and not the image.


[image]

**How can I make the letter on the top face of the cube to appear once the game is played?**

Comment: Have you added the texture to your material? Unwrapping alone is not enough

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos     How can I do that?...Is there any youtube tutorial?

Comment: [Yeah tons of them!](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=vid&q=blender%20game%20engine%20materials) Wonder how you missed them

Answer (score 1):

Select the cube and go to material and make 2 new material.
Select the 1st material and 
Go to texture tab
Go below in the type and change --- Image or movie
and below 3 tabs -- Texture, material, both
Click on Material
In the below image select or open your image
Mapping -- coordinates -- UV
In the N panel go to Shading and change to -- GLSL
Select the cube go to edit mode and click the face u want to texture and press u and unwrap
Go to UV/Image editor and select the image
Now change the view from solid to texture.

Go to the material and select the 2nd color and change ur color.

Change Blender render to game engine